What elements of the MOS 6502 did it copy from the Motorola 6800?
It is not uncommon for microprocessor system designers to copy elements of
design from other microprocessor systems; the Z80, extensively copying
design elements of the 8080, is a notable example.
That the MOS 65xx series copied design elements from the Motorola 68xx
series is not surprising; many of the designers working on that series had
actually come from Motorola, leaving because Motorola was not open to their
idea of doing a new CPU that could be manufactured considerably more
cheaply than the 6800. One obvious direct copy was the MOS 6520 PIA, which
is substantially the same as a Motorola 6821.
What elements of the Motorola 6800 that were substantially characteristic
to it, rather than being "a common way of doing things,"  were copied in
the design of the MOS 6502?
By "a common way of doing things" I'm talking about design elements that
were widespread amongst other processors (microprocessors or otherwise),
versus design elements that that you can clearly identify as being those
of the 6800.
An example of the former would be, "an 8-bit wide accumulator named A on
which you perform ALU operations that set flags," which describes not only
the 6800 and 6502, but also the Intel 8080.
An example of the latter might be, "an additional addressing mode on many
instructions with a shorter address within a subset of memory" (i.e., the
"zero page" addressing mode), though I am not myself sure if that didn't
exist on other processors before the 6800.

The PDP-8 (1965) had a zero-page address mode.

@dave Yes, that came to my mind too, but the PDP-8 was different in that it had only short addresses, so you could access its zero page only with the ZP addressing mode. The 6800 is different in that the ZP addressing mode duplicates functionality of the standard absolute addressing mode, only using a one-byte operand instead of a two-byte operand.

Having preferred address ranges isn't anything new, already the /360 design got a ZP like mode, as the first 4096 bytes were always accessible independent of any base register value. Also, note that the Z80 isn't just taking some elements, but a direct extension. After all, it a slight upgrade and simplification of the 8080, made by the very same lead designer, Frederico Faggin, intended as quick money maker to finance his real new design, the Z8. And the 6502 is essentially the same, except more extreme and with opposite targets. Faggin mainly changed the bus while MOS did go for the ISA.

@Raffzahn "...the Z80 isn't just taking some elements...." I didn't say "taking some," I said "extensively copying." Regardless, your statement is correct but irrelevant to the question. It may not just be taking some elements, but it is indeed "taking some elements," and thus I think serves as a suitable (and particularly obvious) example that microprocessor designers do take elements from other microprocessor designers.

Does the bus interface count? The 6501 is pin-compatible with the 6800, the 6502 rearranged.

The “6”. They copied the “6”…

@Tommy Yes, it does.

@Tommy 6502 not only rearranged it, but also used a different signal combination for cyclevalidation

@cjs_"...example that microprocessor designers do take elements from other microprocessor designers...", erm, no. Point is that /80 did not take elements from some other designer. Federico Faggin was lead designer for both CPU's, 8080 and Z80. The Z80 is a direct continuation of the 8080.Even more than, for example, Mitsubishi's CPUs are a direct continuations of MOS' design.

@Raffzahn Sorry, I misspoke in my previous comment; I meant "other microprocessor designs," as I said in my original question. But I'm sure you can find much more to quibble about that's not really related to the question. Carry on with more pointless comments! We want to make sure that the comment section is noisy enough that we can't find the important things in it!

@cjs Comments are not storage of important things, these sites shall provide their information without the comments. Anything important is supposed to be in the question and in the potential answers. This is not a forum.

@thebusybee I am glad you agree with me about that. Further, comments on questions are for suggesting improvements to the questions, rather than going off on irrelevant tangents.

The 6502 is a modified 6501.  The 6501 was bus-compatible with the 6800, and could be used as a drop-in replacement in the same circuits electrically.  It was this property that led to the legal issues that resulted in the 6502.  The 6502 is perhaps inspired by, or in the same vein, as the 6800 but there is no direct relation.
I think you may be viewing this with a modern perspective (from that of computer architecture).  I'd note that the designers at the time viewed it as an electrical component in a control circuit first, and as a computer second.  That anyone would use these chips in a general purpose computer was a post facto surprise.  They were not looking to innovate in computer architecture!  They copied established ideas from the minicomputers already used in industrial controllers.
So yes, much of the apparent similarity is just "common ways of doing things" at that time.  As some comments and another answer notes, yes the  6501/6502 instruction set and architecture do bear some similarities to the 6800, including the assembly mnemonics.  But they're also similar to the (earlier) DG Nova and some DEC machines (jmp lda sta and friends go back to the 1960s).

I don't think that viewing a microprocessor as a "component in a control circuit first, a computer second" (or vice versa) makes any difference to this question. E.g., zero-page (8-bit) addressing as an adjunct to absolute (16-bit) doesn't depend at all on whether the CPU is being used to control an car or as a general purpose computer.

It would be worth extending your answer to discuss the bus compatibilities between the 6502 and the 6800. The 6502 wasn't pin-for-pin compatible, but the bus and control structure was essentially the same, was it not? Could you, with an adapter, switch a 6800 system to a 6502, or vice versa? And what would be the details of that?  (Looking at the Apple 1 may help you with this.)

From the programmer's perspective: The official mnemonics are pretty similar.
For example



6800
6502




jsr
jsr


rts
rts


rti
rti


bne
bne


beq
beq


lda
lda


sta
sta


asl
asl


lsr
lsr


inx
inx


dex
dex


rol
rol


ror
ror


cmp
cmp


...
...



The Z80 uses a radical new scheme.

Do you mean aren't pretty similar at all? The at all at the end sort of confuses the sentence's meaning. Also, could you [edit] and expand upon your answer a little bit?

"Mnemonics" are not any part of a microprocessor, though.

@dave Mnemonics are part of the specification, do you know an exception?

Instructions are what a CPU executes.  Mnemonics are the input language to an assembler.  You can have the same mnemonics for different instruction sets; you can have different mnemonics for the same instruction set.  Is the point you're making that the instruction sets are "pretty similar"?

Some of those mnemonics clearly did not originate with the 6800; for example, BEQ is also a PDP-11 mnemonic. Others have different sets of addressing modes: LDA always loads the A register on 6502, but may load A or B accumulator on 6800, depending on the operands. Though even the existence of that mnemonic depends on your assembler, some don't use the "official" mnemonics and accept only LDAA or LDAB. And, of course, the Z80 uses a "radical new scheme" for the exact same parts of the CPU design as the 8080 for copyright reasons, yet accepts code assembled from Intel mnemonics.

So no, I don't think that "these things are written down differently in official documentation" is really a fruitful avenue to pursue here; I'm looking for similarities in the design of the CPU itself, regardless of whether or not the documentation for them is different.

BTW, there might be something in that RTI instruction. How did it compare between the 6800 and 6809, and did any other systems do it exactly the same way? It's certainly different from the 8080, which did not push the flags automatically.
